# How to validate Entitiy for only 1 field

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, bean-validation

i have simple question about JPA validator

```
@Entity
class Account {
  @NotNull
  int id;
   @Size(max = 30, min = 6)
  String name;

  @Size(max = 30, min = 5)
  @NotNull
  String password;
}
```

If i call

```
  Set<ConstraintViolation<Account>> constraintViolations =
            validator.validate(account);
```

it will validate all the fields. In some cases, i dont want to valid all the fields. How can i validate only for password?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To do this invoke `validateProperty()` method instead of `validate()`:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Account>> constraintViolations =
    validator.validateProperty(account, "password");
```

See also [example in documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e620)

BTW, there is also method `validateValue()` which may be useful. And groups also may be used to achieve this.